Why does Arkie have stitches?
In the Australian film Scarygirl, the main character has an eyepatch, tentacle, stitches around her mouth, and a hook hand.
The octopus tentacle is explained by the fact that, apparently,

Dr. Maybee made her as a baby from a combination of his daughter's DNA and Blister's, throwing her away when he saw her "imperfections."

However, what explains the stitches, eyepatch and hook? They would certainly fit a Frankenstein's monster aesthetic, but far from being a corpse given life, she seems to be a perfectly normal albeit genetically engineered organism who grew into her current form.

I think the stitches, eyepatch, and hook could be symbols of the trauma Arkie endured as a result of Dr. Maybee's experimentation. So they they might not be literal surgical repairs, but rather visual metaphors for the damage he done..
Basically they are likely artistic and thematic choices

While "it's just a metaphor" is a legitimate answer, I am not sure how this would fit. Maybee got rid of Arkie as soon as she was born, so he didn't actually experiment on her at all, and she cannot remember her infancy as far as we see.  After that, she was raised by Blister from infancy; pretty well, as far as we can see. There's not really any sign of any trauma at all in what we see of her personality until Maybee's bounty hunters capture Blister.
